# Beta testers downloads on Google Play and App Store

Tags: app-store, google-play-games, beta-testing

Will the downloads number of beta-testers dissapear after publishing the release version on Google Play and App Store? If I have, for instance, 1000 downloads from testers, will it positively affect the rating in these markets?

Answer (score 1):

No, the primary purpose of alpha/beta testing is for you to be able to get feedback and improve the quality of your app before releasing the actual production version. It is clearly stated [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html) that whatever stats you gain  during testing phase will never affect your app's public reviews and rating.